# How to list open internet connections in a firejail?

Tags: linux, namespace

I'm using firejail to sandbox firefox. When I use `lsof -i`, there are no connections shown. Firejail does namespace isolation on the process, so i do this

`ps aux | grep firefox  | awk ' { print $2} ' | while read p ; do nsenter -t $p lsof -i ; done`

to enter each namespace and to lsof -i. I've tried `nsenter -t <pid> -n lsof -i` as well but nothing appears. But this works when I lsof as root. Shouldn't a user be able to list open socket connections?

Answer (score 0):

That `ps | grep | awk` pipeline is as ugly as it is ancient (which is **very** ancient).

BTW, the `grep` will match its own pid....which is why most variants use some trick to exclude grep's pid.  Usually something horrible like `ps aux | grep command | grep -v grep`.  The best of them use a bracket expression for grep's regex. And even better versions realise that piping `grep` into `awk` is almost always redundantly pointless, not required, and even unnecessary because `awk` can do regex pattern matches, and end up with something like `ps aux | awk '/[c]ommand/ {print $2}'`).

Anyway, don't use any of that hideous nonsense.  It should have died in the 90s, but its zombified corpse keeps getting resurrected or re-invented.

Use `pgrep` or `ps` with the `h` (no headers), `-C` (match cmdlist) and `-o` (output formatting) options instead.  That's what they're for.

e.g.

```
pgrep -f firefox | xargs -I {} nsenter -n -t {} lsof -i
```

or

```
ps h -C firefox -o pid | xargs -I {} nsenter -n -t {} lsof -i
```

or, without `xargs`:

```
for pid in $(pgrep -f firefox) ; do
  nsenter -n -t "$pid" lsof -i
done
```

That's far from perfect, but it's a far better starting point that what you're currently doing.

BTW, `pgrep` can list all the PIDs in a namespaces.  And there's also `lsns` for examining and extracting all sorts of details about namespaces.  And even `ps` has options for listing the various namespaces associated with a PID.  You probably should read the man pages for all of these....especially if you want to list network connections in a namespace that doesn't have either its own `lsof` binary or a mapping to the system's lsof and/or /usr/bin/ directory.

Unfortunately, `lsof` itself doesn't seem to have any built in namespace support....maybe in some future version.

Comment: It's all the same to me, but have you tried it with firejail? Or some kind of unshare?

Comment: lsns on my machine displays only the current namespace, but not every namespace of the user is shown. Also the current firefox seems to use GeckoMain in the comm field, so pgrep doesn't work on pgrep firefox, but pgrep -f firefox does. nsenter with lsof -i doesn't show the network connections on my machine.

Comment: All of the above examples worked for me when I tested them against gitlab which I'm running in docker.  I also tested with firefox but, because I don't run firefox in a container, it ran `lsof -i` in the default namespace and listed everything.  Doesn't matter, the examples above do what they're supposed to do and run `lsof -i` in the process's namespace.    and yes, you need to use the `-f` option with `pgrep` to search for firefox.  That's why I had it in my answer.

Comment: The point is lsof -i isn't showing all open network connections from within a firejail firefox profile. And neither is lsns showing the other namespaces - as in other namespaces that have created by the same user. In this case it seems like a user can run something that uses a network connection, and won't be able to see lsof -i it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that firefox seems to create another sandbox for the running and derived firefox processes. So if a user starts firejail with firefox on the command line, lsns will show for the current user.

But, if from the same command line I grep for all firefox processes, and nsenter into the net namespace, `lsof -i` fails with:

`nsenter: cannot open /proc/8958/ns/net: Permission denied`

As root, lsns shows the firefox processes and the associated pids for every namespace. If I enter into all the namespaces and `lsof -i`, I get the output of firefox sockets for some pids.

When I `ls` the /proc/pid, where the pid uid is the user and had generated lsof -i output, the files are all owned by root and not by the user which is why `lsof -i` does not work when executed as a user on all firefox processes.

It's difficult to say if this is expected behaviour, so any input would be appreciated.